# Devise /users/confirmation route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, confirmation, devise-confirmable

Cant Confirm email, with devise.

**route.rb**

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" ,:omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" } do
    post   "users/confirmation",          :to => "devise/confirmations#create"
    get    "users/confirmation/new",      :to => "devise/confirmations#new", :as => "new_confirmation"
    get    "users/confirmation",          :to => "devise/confirmations#show"
  end
  resources :pensioners #, :only => [:index, :destroy, :new]
  resources :users #, :only => [:index, :destroy, :new]
```

**heroku run rake routes**

```
                                                             ....
   user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format) devise/confirmations#create

   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new

                  GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)          devise/confirmations#show

                                                              ....
```

But when I make **request**

```
    GET /users/confirmation?confirmation_token=BeELxDDq9sxpseLh8Rdn
```

I get 404 **error**

```
  The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
  You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

Where am I wrong at?

**Model**:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      devise .... , :confirmable
```

**Migration**:

```
class AddConfirmableToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
   add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
   add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
   add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
   add_index :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
   User.update_all(:confirmed_at => Time.now)
  end
  ....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kinda late, but anyway. Try to use a PATCH instead of GET. Your `routes.rb` should have a route like

```
patch '/user/confirmation' => 'user/confirmations#update', :via => :patch, :as => :update_user_confirmation
```

Comment: @issy sorry for late response. Here it is if you still need it: `patch '/user/confirmation' => 'user/confirmations#update', :via => :patch, :as => :update_user_confirmation`

Comment: I couldn't understand how to apply that fix, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Saibot I've updated an answer but don't know what else can I say. I haven't been used devise for a long long time now.

Comment: I'm new to web development, so it was not easy to figure out this fix belongs to routes. :) Found it myself after a couple hours, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Saibot glad you figured it out! I believe that self-learning is the most useful. Anyway, have a nice journey :)

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.2.10, with Devise 4.4.3, this worked for me:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations',
                                  sessions: 'sessions',
                                  confirmations: 'confirmations' }
devise_scope :user do
  # custom routes...
  get 'confirmation/sent' => 'confirmations#sent'
  patch 'users/confirmation' => 'confirmations#create'
end
```